# Scrolling RecyclerView and siblings in a Viewpager, in a CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-appcompat

I am trying to implement a view with the following structure

```
MainActivity
    CoordinatorLayout
        ViewPager
            Fragment (root view, RelativeLayout)
                TextView
                RecyclerView
```

Or, having a RecyclerView with a sibling in a Fragment, placed in a ViewPager, in a CoordinatorLayout.

The layout can be seen in this video, as well as the issue: https://youtu.be/1oAqEpg7N4I

I would like for the TextView to scroll along with the RecyclerView, however the TextView currently stays in place and the RecyclerView scrolls on it's own underneath it. You can see the effect in the video.

I have found demos of dealing with a RecyclerView in a ViewPager, but I can't find any that use a heading like I do.

I have tried introducing a NestedScrollView as a parent of the Viewpager, as the root of the fragment layout, and the ScrollView can only have one parent so I can't add it to wrap the TextView and RecyclerView.

Here is my CoordinatorLayout implementation. It can be found on Github as well at https://github.com/vidia/MaterialDiningCourts/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_meal_view.xml for context if needed.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            ...
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            ...
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foregroundGravity="top"
            ... />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not place your text view within your recycler view so it scrolls with the content of the recycler view within your viewpager?

Comment: I was thinking of that. But that seems like a hack to me. The recyclerview should really just contain the list IMO, and it shouldnt have to contain my header like that. TI may just do that anyway though, but I won't say it is a good solution.